# How to convert [array([[]])] to 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays

So I have some data which are in this format:

```
[array([[0.00849484],[0.00830291],[0.00735711]]) array([[0.00795935],[0.00772346],[0.00740238]])...]
```

How can I convert it into simple 1D array?

```
[0.00849484 0.00830291 0.00735711 0.00795935 0.00772346 0.00740238]
```

Comment: are those arrays numpy?

Comment: `np.array(a).ravel().tolist()`.

Comment: @aaronn yes, numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

if a is array

```
a = np.array([np.array([[0.00849484],[0.00830291],[0.00735711]]), np.array([[0.00795935],[0.00772346],[0.00740238]])])
```

result

```
array([[[0.00849484],
        [0.00830291],
        [0.00735711]],

       [[0.00795935],
        [0.00772346],
        [0.00740238]]])
```

use flatten

```
a.flatten()
```

result (numpy array)

```
array([0.00849484, 0.00830291, 0.00735711, 0.00795935, 0.00772346,
       0.00740238])
```

```
a.flatten().tolist()
```

result (python list)

```
[0.00849484, 0.00830291, 0.00735711, 0.00795935, 0.00772346,
       0.00740238]
```